# How to get historical Slack call id's?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is there a way to get historical call ID's from the Slack API?

I would like to use the slack `calls.info` API (https://api.slack.com/methods/calls.info) to get information on past Slack calls.  But I cannot find a way to get the ID's of the calls.  (The only way per the documentation is the data returned by the `calls.add` API

I can see evidence in Slack of my past calls with other users, but when I call `conversations.history`, I do not see any data for calls...just messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no method that will return call ids retroactively.Something like `calls.list` would be helpful. Right now, I think your only option would be to store the ids when you call `calls.add`moving forward so that you can then use them in future `calls.info` calls.

Comment: Did anything change regarding this in the meantime? [I'm also looking for a solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/comments/115jiuf/call_history_with_call_length_via_api/).